# I use Acceleo to create Java main method, but "[]" causes trouble because Acceleo redeems this as invocation

Tags: templates, acceleo, mtl-file

I am using Acceleo to create Java main method in my ".mtl", like this

```
[template public generateElement(aMiniFamily : MiniFamily)]
[comment @main/]
[file ('CreateMiniFamily.java', false, 'UTF-8')]
public static void main(String[] args) {
    }
[/file]
[/template]
```

But Acceleo gives me error as "**The invocation isn't terminated**" around "**String[]**".

I tried with "\[]" and "/[]", not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The acceleo template syntax is kind of annoying when you want to print `[]`, but there's a very simple way to go over this issue, it's to remember that Acceleo will evaluate OCL expressions inside of the `[ /]`. Consequently, you can put a string inside of the `[/]` and it will be printed as a string in your result file. The expression will then be `['[]'/]` and your code:

```
[template public generateElement(aMiniFamily : MiniFamily)]
[comment @main/]
[file ('CreateMiniFamily.java', false, 'UTF-8')]
public static void main(String['[]'/] args) {
}
[/file]
[/template]
```